# Call function in user parameter definition

Tags: jmeter

I'm running a set of thread groups (consecutively) and I need to reset a number of parameters at the start of each thread group so that they have a unique value.

Presently I'm referencing a `User Paramaters` node using a test fragment, and setting the value to `value-${__time()}`. Unfortunately, this results in the value being used verbatim (without resolving the time).

Is there a better way to achieve per-thread group variables that include function calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me (Jmeter 2.5.1), as per below example.
Sample params set to `${__time(HMS,)}` and `value-${__time()}` successfully resolved, generated and updated (once per iteration) for each thread (in this case:3 Thread Groups, 5 threads @ 3 loops).

[image: user params example]

Can you please answer why are you using User Parameters via [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) (as per your post)?

...And several articles, just fyi:
[Parametrization in JMeter with user parameter](http://www.sujitnayak.com/?p=109)
[JMeter Variables vs. Properties. vs. Parameters](http://coreplex.blogspot.com/2008/10/jmeter-variables-vs-properties-vs.html)

**UPDATED:**

Please find below results for example with both User Params and test logic put into Test Fragment and called from Module Controllers.
Works the same way as in sample above: successfully resolved, preserved between samplers in separate loop and updated (once per iteration) between loops for each thread (well, I 've commented in screen the rest of thread groups to get output for the first only; works fine with all TGs enabled too).

[image: user params example with test fragment]

I think you could also try to put User Params config from Test Fragment to each thread group and leave in Test Fragment only test logic - if the above schema will still not work for you:

[image: user params example with test fragment]

It's not very nice but both the Module Controller and Include Controller are still quite "buggy" and sometimes unpredictable.

You could also try to debug problem controllers in your scenario: select controller > click Help in jmeter's main menu > click Enable Debug > look into jmeter.log for details after execution.

You could also look onto custom [Parameterized Controller](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ParameterizedController) - maybe it will work better.

Comment: RE User Parameters in a Test Fragment, because it avoids duplication of the User Parameters node.

Comment: Can you try the following? Instead of duplicating User Paramters + BeanShell Sampler, move it into a test fragment and call a Module Controller to each thread to run that test fragment. When I do that, the variable doesn't resolve.

Comment: It turns out I was missing an end brace on one of my function calls. I'm marking this as the answer for the alternatives provided and the info on enabling debug (which helped me diagnose the problem).